# Validate JSON file in Visual Basic

Tags: json, vb.net, visual-studio, json.net, schema

I'm trying to validate a JSON file in Visual Basic code. I've been looking for documentation on Newtonsoft however, they only offer sample code in C#. I basically want to use a schema string to validate some JSON files from a database in VB. How would the code below (written in C#) look like if it was written in VB?

How do you write
`JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaJson);`
In Visual Basic Code?

```
string schemaJson = @"{
  'description': 'A person',
  'type': 'object',
  'properties':
  {
    'name': {'type':'string'},
    'hobbies': {
      'type': 'array',
      'items': {'type':'string'}
    }
  }
}";

JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaJson);

JObject person = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'name': 'James',
  'hobbies': ['.NET', 'Blogging', 'Reading', 'Xbox', 'LOLCATS']
}");

bool valid = person.IsValid(schema);
// true
```

Comment: Dim schema as JsonSchema = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaJson)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Some websites](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=convert%20c%23%20to%20vb.net&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS945US945&oq=convert%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j35i39j0j69i60j69i65l2j69i60.3614j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) can help you convert the C# code to VB.NET.

Here's the result of the conversion:

```
    Dim schemaJson As String = "{
      'description': 'A person',
      'type': 'object',
      'properties':
      {
        'name': {'type':'string'},
        'hobbies': {
          'type': 'array',
          'items': {'type':'string'}
        }
      }
    }"
    Dim schema As JsonSchema = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaJson)
    Dim person As JObject = JObject.Parse("{
      'name': 'James',
      'hobbies': ['.NET', 'Blogging', 'Reading', 'Xbox', 'LOLCATS']
    }")
    Dim valid As Boolean = person.IsValid(schema)
```

Answer (score 0):

Start of your "C# for VB Devs cheat sheet":

```
Variable declaration - developer declares type

C#: Type name
VB: Dim name as Type

Variable declaration - compiler infers type

C#: var name
VB: Dim name

Variable assignment

C#: name = ...
VB: name = ...

End of statement

C#: ;
VB: <CRLF>

Continuation of statement across lines

C#: <CRLF>
VB: _<CRLF>
```